# expanded sub menu collapsed when page reload

Tags: bootstrap, menú

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un menú lateral vertical y cuando doy click sobre alguna opción en el menú o sub opción del menú, se recarga la pagina y el menú se vuelve a contraer. Me gustaría saber como puedo mantener seleccionada la opción del menú que yo elegí después de haber recargado la pagina.

Estoy usando metisMenu (para el menú lateral vertical), Boostrapt 3.x, para el maquetado, y VS 2017 con Razor.

Comment: Pero quieres que al recargar la página se mantenga el menú o derechamente que no recargue la página?

Comment: Hola, lo que necesito es que al recargar la pagina, se mantenga el menú lateral abierto en donde di click. En mi menú lateral actual, tengo hasta 3 niveles de opciones. Por ejemplo Menú 1 => Reportes => Reporte Stock. Al dar Click sobre "Reporte Stock" se recarga la pagina y me muestra el reporte, solo que el menú se colapsa y pierdo la referencia de cual fue la opción que yo elegí. Espero ser claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunca he usado metisMenu así que seguramente hay una solución más elegante.

Pero con lo que alcancé a mirar la documentación, creo que una opción, algo artesanal, sería darle a tus submenús un ID que se pudiera relacionar a la URL donde conducen, de manera que al cargarlas pudieras usar la propiedad `location.hash` o `location.pathname` para identificar qué submenú está activo.

En estos snippets no puedo hacer una navegación real, pero lo simulé usando un `setTimeout`. Al pinchar un submenú se colapsa todo. Al final del timeOut se reinstancia el metisMenu marcando como activo el subitem cuyo ID coincide con lo último que pinché.

```js
function restoreSelected(current_url) {
  var activo = jQuery(current_url);
  $('#status').text('Estamos en:');
  activo.addClass('selected');
  activo.closest('ul').closest('li').find('a').first().click();
}

// Esto sería reemplazado por la navegación real
function simularNavegacion(next_url) {
  $('metismenu').metisMenu('dispose');
  $('#status').text('Cargando...')
  $('#contenido').text('Espere mientras cargamos ' + next_url);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#contenido').text('Pantalla  ' + next_url);
    $("#metismenu").metisMenu({
      toggle: false
    });
    restoreSelected(next_url);
  }, 3000);
}

function navigateToNextUrl(next_url) {
  var activeitems = $('#metismenu').find('.mm-active');
  activeitems.removeClass('mm-active');
  activeitems.find('a').attr('aria-expanded', false);
  activeitems.find('ul.mm-show').removeClass('mm-show');
  activeitems.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  simularNavegacion(next_url);
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#metismenu").metisMenu({
    toggle: false
  });

  $('#metismenu li li a').on('click', function() {
    var next_url = $(this).attr('href');
    navigateToNextUrl(next_url);
  });

});
```

```css
#metismenu li {
  padding: 3px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#metismenu li a {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#metismenu li ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#metismenu li li {
  background: #555;
}

#metismenu li li:hover,
#metismenu li li.selected {
  background: #999;
}

#metismenu li li.selected a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/metismenu"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-xs-4">
      <nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul id="metismenu">
          <li id="menu1" class="">
            <a href="#" class="has-arrow" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li id="Menu1Option1">
                <a href="#Menu1Option1">Menu 1 Option 1</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu1Option2">
                <a href="#Menu1Option2">Menu 1 Option 2</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu1Option3">
                <a href="#Menu1Option3">Menu 1 Option 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu2">
            <a href="#" class="has-arrow" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li id="Menu2Option1">
                <a href="#Menu2Option1">Menu 2 Option 1</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu2Option2">
                <a href="#Menu2Option2">Menu 2 Option 2</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu2Option3">
                <a href="#Menu2Option3">Menu 2 Option 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu3">
            <a href="#" class="has-arrow" aria-expanded="false">Menu 3</a>
            <ul>
              <li id="Menu3Option1">
                <a href="#Menu3Option1">Menu 3 Option 1</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu3Option2">
                <a href="#Menu3Option2">Menu 3 Option 2</a>
              </li>
              <li id="Menu3Option3">
                <a href="#Menu3Option3">Menu 3 Option 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div id="status">Estamos en:</div>
      <div><b id="contenido">Pantalla inicial</b></div>
    </div>

  </div>
```